# Electron Router TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm developing an application with Electron and using Electron Router to manage routes. I encountered an error stating "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined", specifically at line 155 of the router.js file. It seems there's an issue accessing properties or methods of the Router instance I create. Upon investigation, I found that the root of the problem is related to the "remote" module, which is deprecated in Electron. This module appears to be used by Electron Router to determine the process type (main or renderer). I need assistance in resolving this issue and ensuring that my application functions correctly.

The line that causes the error is the following one:
return remote.hasOwnProperty('getCurrentWindow')

I'm working with Electron version 28.2.3, and initially, I was using version 0.4.1 of electron-router. I thought that updating it to the latest version, 0.5.1, would solve the issue, but unfortunately, it didn't work. I don't have enough knowledge about the dependency to resolve this problem.

I also considered migrating from electron-router to react-router-dom. However, since electron-router is extensively used across all my .js files to interconnect them, and there's no React development involved, I'm unsure if installing only the react dependency would cause any issues with other parts of the application.

Comment: It looks like there is a replacement for the deprecated built-in `remote`: https://github.com/electron/remote.  You may be able to drop that in as a replacement.

Comment: @DanielBeck This is a bad advice, remote has been deprecated ror a reason. The correct *and* secure way is [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). Just use React Router.

Comment: I thought the warnings on the linked repo were sufficient, but yes, agreed, continuing to use deprecated packages isn't ideal.